# How do I tell Cargo to build files other than main.rs?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Here is my directory structure:

```
lowks@lowkster ~/src/rustlang/gettingrusty $ tree .
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── foo.txt
├── src
│   ├── boolean_example.rs
│   ├── function_goodbye_world.rs
│   ├── listdir.rs
│   ├── looping.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── pattern_match.rs
│   └── write_to_file.rs
└── target
    ├── build
    ├── deps
    ├── examples
    ├── gettingrusty
    └── native

6 directories, 11 files
```

When I run 'cargo build', it seems to only build `main.rs`. How should I change Cargo.toml to build the rest of the files too?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Rust compiler compiles all the files at the same time to build a **crate**, which is either an executable or a library. To add files to your crate, add `mod` items to your crate root (here, main.rs) or to other modules:

```
mod boolean_example;
mod function_goodbye_world;
mod listdir;
mod looping;
mod pattern_match;
mod write_to_file;
```

To access items defined in another module from your crate root, you must qualify that item with the module name. For example, if you have a function named `foo` in module `looping`, you must refer to it as `looping::foo`.

You can also add `use` statements to import names in the module's scope. For example, if you add `use looping::foo;`, then you can just use `foo` to refer to `looping::foo`.

For more information, see [*Separating Modules into Different Files*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html) in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Answer (score 45):

Put `other.rs` file into `bin` subfolder of `src` folder (`./src/bin/other.rs`). And run `cargo build --bin other` or `cargo run --bin other`

Comment: This also works by running `cargo build` . No need to append the file name.

Answer (score 19):

There are a few different [types of binaries or targets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html) that cargo recognizes:

- [binaries](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries)
- [libraries](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#library)
- [benchmarks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#benchmarks)
- [integration tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#tests)
- [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#examples)

For example, if the file `boolean_example.rs` is a standalone example that you want to run you can put in inside an `examples` directory and tell cargo about it like so:

```
[[example]]
name = "boolean" # examples/boolean.rs
```

This lets you invoke your example with `cargo run --example boolean`

Read the cargo book's page on [package layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) as well to see how these target directories can be structured.

Comment: What file do you put this description into ?

Comment: @bokan You put that in `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score -3):

**you can include your testing in the main.rs file as following >>**

Filename: src/main.rs

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
  #[test]
 fn this_test_will_pass() {
    let value = 4;
    assert_eq!(4, value);
  }

  #[test]
  fn this_test_will_fail() {
    let value = 8;
    assert_eq!(5, value);
  }
}
```

*Or call them from your tests file.*
then run them using test command: `cargo test`

from filename: lib/tests.rs

```
mod tests;

tests::run();
```

- 

> in this case main.rs will be built but only tests.rs file will be
> executed.

- 

#### more prove:

[image: exmaple]