# How to specify crates to rustc in command-line?

Tags: random, rust, package, command-line-interface, rust-crates

I'm trying to use `rand::random` function in Rust:

```
use rand::random;

fn main(){
  println!("{}",rand::random::<f64>());
}
```

It didn't work, the `rand` crate was not installed by default. So I installed it:

```
$ cargo install rand
```

However, after installing `rand` crate, the programme is still not running, error:

```
  |
8 | use rand::random;
  |     ^^^^ maybe a missing crate `rand`?
```

I wish to use `rustc` command instead of `cargo` as I need to specify different programme files instead of `main.rs`:

```
rustc -L rand myprog.rs
```

How to use crates with `rustc` command?

Comment: You might be interested in [How do I tell Cargo to build files other than main.rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613874/how-do-i-tell-cargo-to-build-files-other-than-main-rs)

Comment: i prefer the raw rustc  for just trying out

Comment: never mind, i use cargo for now